# Required Attribute wont work on with addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

My goal is that passing data from a form to another element.
My code works when passing the data, but the time when the form is empty and user attempt to press the button, the `required` attribute won't work even tho I put the attribute to every form inputs. I want to prevent user submitting empty data.

Here's a sample [code](https://jsfiddle.net/smz6w8o4/33/)

```js
const passBtn = document.querySelector("#btnSubmit");
const inputEmail = document.querySelector("#inputEmail");
const recieveText = document.querySelector("#recieveText");
const getEmail = document.querySelector("#getEmail");

passBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  getEmail.textContent = inputEmail.value;

})
```

```html
<form legend="Form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      MyForm
    </legend>
    <input id="inputEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">
          Pass Text
        </button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>
    Recieved Text Here
  </p>
  <div class="content-wrapper">


    <span id="getEmail"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What behavior are you expecting, and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (Re *"Here's a sample code"* -- your full example should be **here, on-site**, not off site. People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you, when you put things off-site it's easy to leave out important parts, and some sites are blocked for some users.)

Comment: Side note: In general, prefer `document.getElementById("id")` to `document.querySelector("#id")`. The former doesn't have to parse a CSS selector to figure out that you're getting by ID. (Obviously, if the selector is dynamic and may or may not be an ID selector, that's different, but for hardcoded ones best to use the right tool for the job. :-) )

Comment: I apologize, I'm still in a process of learning JS, this is just a quick and simplified code from my project just to have an idea of what my code's logic looks like. I am expecting a warning/dialouge from a form "Please fill up this form" will appear when user press the Button with an empty form. Adding more context: The project's purpose is to registring Employee's Data then passing it to a Table and Object/Map. Object because I just learned Data structure, and might help me to understand how that works.

Comment: Also noted on that snippet, I'm still new here though, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for having the form validation triggered you need to listen to the form submit event and for that you can change your code to:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
const inputEmail = document.querySelector("#inputEmail");
const recieveText = document.querySelector("#recieveText");
const getEmail = document.querySelector("#getEmail");



form.addEventListener("submit",function(e){
e.preventDefault();
getEmail.textContent = inputEmail.value;

/* recieveText.value = inputEmail.value; */

})
```

and also you need to have a name attribute for elements as well:
then update:

```
<input id="inputEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
```

to

```
<input id="inputEmail" type="email" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ko5py9cw/

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of the "submit" Edit: Also noted on the Name attribute, I shouldve always remember to use that to inputs and forms, thanks again !